# Don't Repeat Yourself

Tags: javascript, jquery

Would like to know if there is a better way to write this small block of code keeping DRY in mind.  I see the similarities in the functions of course, but I am not sure how to shorten it. Also, I would like to know how much of a difference the shortening would make if any.  Thank you,  Jason

```js
var adminAlert = {

  alert: function() {

    var sumAlert = sumSupport = sumCashout = sumPhone = 0;

    $.getJSON("alertFeed.JSON", function(data) {

      $.each(data.alertData, function(i, allAlerts) {

        sumAlert += parseFloat(allAlerts.value);
        sumSupport += parseFloat(allAlerts.support);
        sumCashout += parseFloat(allAlerts.cashout);
        sumPhone += parseFloat(allAlerts.phone);

        $(".alertPoints").html(sumAlert);
        $(".support-requests").html(sumSupport);
        $(".cashout-giftcards").html(sumCashout);
        $(".phone-verification").html(sumPhone);
      });
    });
  }
};
```

Comment: If you have working code and want to improve it, [Code Review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/) is usually a good place to go. Also, when you do `var sumAlert = sumSupport = sumCashout = sumPhone = 0`, you're (unintentionally?) declaring the last 3 variables globally.

Comment: Also, `$(".alertPoints").html(sumAlert);` etc doesn't need to be inside the `$.each` loop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The version undernearth is more DRY. Basically, to make your code DRY, you:

1. Identify repeated stuff. In your case it was `parseFloat(allAlerts.foobar)` and `$(".blablabla").html(foobar)`;
2. Identify what is different between those repetitions. In your case you used a series of 4 keys within the `allAlerts` object: `'value'`, `'support'`, `'cashout'` and `'phone'`. Each of those 4 keys correspond to a CSS selector, e.g. `cashout` corresponds to `".cashout-giftcards"`;
3. Take what you identified in step 2 and put it into a declarative map. In your case:

```js
{
    'value': 'alertPoints',
    'support': 'support-requests',
    'cashout': 'cashout-giftcards',
    'phone': 'phone-verification'
}
```

4. Replace what you identified in step 1 with a more unified / abstract code using the map you created in step 3. In your case, the four lines like `sumCashout += parseFloat(allAlerts.cashout);` can be replaced with only one line like `sum[k] = parseFloat(allAlerts[k])`

```
var
// To avoid repeatedly doing stuff like $(".alertPoints").html(sumAlert),
// we'll declare a concise map defining what will be updated by what:
    map = {
        'value': 'alertPoints', // later we will use this to update $(".alertPoints") with what comes from allAlerts.value
        'support': 'support-requests', // later we will use this to update $(".support-requests") with what comes from allAlerts.support
        'cashout': 'cashout-giftcards',
        'phone': 'phone-verification'
    },
    adminAlert = {
        alert: function(){
            var
                // Let's define an object that will hold the sums for us
                sum = {},
                // And also a variable to iterate our map;
                k;
            $.getJSON("alertFeed.JSON", function(data) {
                $.each(data.alertData, function(i, allAlerts) {
                    // So we have 4 things to sum and update.
                    // They all are defined in our map.
                    // Lets go through the map and get things done:
                    for (k in map) {
                        // The value of k will be "value", "support" etc...
                        if (!(k in sum)) {
                            // In case the `sum` object does not yet have a key equal to the value of `k`, we initiate it.
                            // This is to have a start value of 0 to start adding to it:
                            sum[k] = 0;
                        }
                        // This is effectively the same as
                        // sumAlert += parseFloat(allAlerts.value) etc. etc.
                        // but written in unified manner to cover all the four cases.
                        // So when say `k` equals to `cashout`, this
                        // will be the same as `sum.cashout += parseFloat(allAlerts.cashout)`
                        sum[k] += parseFloat(allAlerts[k]);
                        // Again, a unified version of
                        // $(".alertPoints").html(sumAlert) etc. etc.
                        $('.' + map[k]).html(sum[k]);
                    }
                });                
            });
        }
    };
```

In terms of difference — it is just easier to maintain / fix / debug / extend etc. Performance will probably be about the same.

Comment: Wow, That was a quick response!  Thank you very much!  Sorry to ask this (and if you have a second) could you put in some comments about what is happening along the way in this code.  I am going to use it but Its a bit advanced and I think its not a good idea to use code I don't fully understand.  Thanks again!

Comment: Yep, answer updated, added comments and explanation. Ask if anything is still unclear.

Comment: You are very helful DrakeES...I appreciate it very much!

Comment: Haha, I would much more appreciate if you told that by upvoting the answer LOL

Comment: I will...I just need to figure out how to obtian 15 reputation points!  haha